# How to show bootstrap popup calendar on gridview row edit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` and I am using bootstrap datetime picker on `gridview` edit mode. The popup calendar show is not working properly. It shows above the grid. Here is the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

When I click on gridview `edit` row then the `calendar` popup shows above the grid. And also let me know how to get this textbox value on gridview row edit command.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
       $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ClientIDMode="Static" OnRowCommand ="GridView1_RowCommand"         Width ="100%" Height ="80px" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="OpenEventID"  OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"   BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3">  
          <Columns>  
                <asp:BoundField  ReadOnly="true"   DataField="OpenEventID" HeaderText="OPEN EVENT NO" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>

     <asp:Label runat="server" ID='lblDate' Text='<%# Eval("Open_Created_Date") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>

<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="datetimepicker1"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
       <%--<asp:BoundField   ReadOnly="true"  DataField="Open_Created_Date" HeaderText="Open Event Created" />--%>

       <asp:BoundField   ReadOnly="true"  DataField="Created_Date" HeaderText="Close Event Created" />
       <asp:BoundField    DataField="Downtime" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Downtime" /> 
       <asp:BoundField  ReadOnly="true"  DataField="FLEET_NO" HeaderText="Asset" /> 
       <asp:BoundField   DataField="CloseWorkDesc" HeaderText="Close Work Description" />

       <asp:BoundField    ReadOnly="true" DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" />

       <asp:BoundField  ReadOnly="true"   DataField="Close_Event_Created" HeaderText="Close Event Created By" /> 
       <asp:BoundField    DataField="HOD_Remarks"    HeaderText="Remarks" />
                          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve" >
<ItemTemplate>

       <asp:Button ID="btnclosevent" Visible ="false"  style="background-color:red;color:white;" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="closeevent"
                    Text="Approve" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OpenEventID") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update" ItemStyle-BackColor ="green" ItemStyle-ForeColor="white" >
            <ItemTemplate >
        <asp:LinkButton  ID="lnkedit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ForeColor ="White" ></asp:LinkButton>

</ItemTemplate>
         <edititemtemplate>
         <asp:linkbutton id="btnUpdate" ForeColor ="White"  runat="server" commandname="Update" text="Update" />
         <asp:linkbutton id="btnCancel" ForeColor="White" runat="server" commandname="Cancel" text="Cancel" />
         </edititemtemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true"  ItemStyle-BackColor ="red" ItemStyle-ForeColor="white" HeaderText="Delete"/>

         <asp:BoundField    DataField="Event_Close" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hide" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hide"     HeaderText="Event_Close" />
         <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-BackColor="Red"  ItemStyle-ForeColor ="White" HeaderText="Status" >
<ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblstatus"   runat="server"  ></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

      </Columns>  
      <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
      <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
      <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
      <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
      <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I want bootstrap popup date time calendar on a specific row which is edited.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use special library for it, for example:
http://ui-grid.info/ - for creating table + change template (for using datetimepicker) + enable editable cell property

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a CSS issue with bootstrap datepicker

since you are using asp.net Gridview then [AjaxControl Toolkit](http://www.ajaxtoolkit.net) would be best choice for you

AjaxControl Toolkit contains `CalenderExtendercontrol` which will have Property called `PopupPosition="BottomLeft"`

Comment: Thanks for response, please can you modify my code? I am using bootstrap datetime picker not ajax control ki, so i cannot use ajax PopupPosition="BottomLeft" property in bootstrap control

Comment: is `ajaxControlToolKit` provide `datetime` picker calendar? I don't want just calendar, i also want choose date with time as well.

Comment: Not Possible ```Ajax Calendar``` doesn't have Time selection. Instead why can't you try Jquery date time picker

[Jquery DateTime Picker example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-Calendar-Extender-control-with-Time-in-ASPNet.aspx)